# CMake search path configuration

Tags: cmake, dependencies

we working on a C++/CMake project, that needs to run in both Windows and Linux. On Windows, we have to work with a number Visual Studio versions, both in 32- and 64 bit. In order to alleviate dependency issues in our team, we have manually compiled a number of dependencies for each configuration(vs2013_x64, vs2013_x86, vs2012_x64, vs2013_x86...) and installed them (using make install or similar commands) to a common folder for each configuration. Now we have a folder called "vs2013_x64" for example, that contains similar folders as /usr would on linux: CMake, include, lib, share, ...

Now my question is: How do I have to set up CMake, so that it treats this vs2013_x64 folder just like it does /usr on Linux?
I found a number of variables that seem related, for example
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and CMAKE_SYSROOT. However, setting them to my vs2013_x64 folder for example does not work: FindXXX.cmake files in the vs2013_x64/CMake folder are not found, and even when I manually set the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to that CMake folder, the Find* scripts are unable to find the include they are looking for, because the vs2013_x64/include folder does not appear to be searched.

A solution that did work was to set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. This is nice and almost what I need, but lets say that on Linux, I would not want it to look at /usr at all under any circumstances. This would not be possible using the PREFIX_PATH solution if I understand it correctly.
From what I understood from the documentation, 
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is more configurable and has a number of additional variables such as CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM, CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY and CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE. This makes me believe that FIND_ROOT_PATH is what I actually SHOULD be doing - yet I am unable to make it work

Does what I am trying to do make sense? Can anyone clarify when and how to use what? Ideally, I would like a solution that allows me to set the search path to my vs2013_x64 folder on Windows, that defaults to /usr on Linux, but can optionally also be set to another directory containing lib/include/cmake folders. In addition, it would be nice if searching ONLY occurred in the configured path and nowhere else (to avoid mistakenly picking a library that was installed system-wide).

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `ExternalProject_Add` serve you need better than pre-compiling libraries?

Comment: Hm well I am talking about deps like Boost, OpenCV etc... I feel like this is the right way to handle those kind of dependencies.

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought about a in-house library. CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is the right way to go, you have to add `NO_DEFAULT_PATH`. See for example https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/find_library.html

Comment: Hm thank you I did not notice this parameter. However I would have to specify it for every find_package call, which seems a little tedious but at least possible. Can you explain when I would be using the variables I mentioned? Like SYSROOT or FIND_ROOT_PATH, and when I would use the PREFIX_PATH? I am a bit confused what the best practice is...